# Highcharts: Cannot get example to display chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I cannot get the following chart to display. The following is the jQuery. I've tried other examples by replacing the jQuery and it works. I have all my files in the same folder, including data.csv.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column'
        },
        < ...more options here... >
    };


    $.get('./data.csv', function (data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');

            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                });
            }

            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else {
                var series = {
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
                    } else {
                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });

                options.series.push(series);

            }

        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

The CSV file looks like:

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15
```

Here is the example I am trying to get working:

http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm

**EDIT: I just realized that the chart displays on Firefox. I have been using Chrome. Very weird. However, the example link above works on both.**

Comment: Can you show working fiddle?

Comment: have you checked how series data looks after you fill it with csv?

Comment: How your CSV looks like? Parser should be appropriate to structure of file (I mean reconigise categories / series names and vlaues)

Comment: Added the CSV file in the question.

Comment: Do you have an errors?  Also, log your lines variable to make sure its returning as you expect.

Comment: I'm using a basic text editor still but I'll install eclipse soon.

Comment: I just realized that the chart displays on Firefox. I have been using Chrome. Very weird. However, the example link I posted works on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome you are not allowed to use AJAX to get local files. If you want do such thing use XAMPP or WAMP to create local server. Firefox doens't have such limits.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this Chrome switch as a temporary fix to allow local file usage: --allow-file-access-from-files