# Replicate Highcharts csv Example

Tags: jquery, firefox, csv, highcharts

First post here, I appreciate the patience. I am trying to replicate the Highcharts example on how to process data from a csv file, described [here](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file) and demonstrated [here](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm).

I right click the demonstration chart, view source, and copy + paste into a new htm file on my hard drive called "test". I create a file named data.csv and save it in the same directory as test.htm. When I open test.htm, it is blank. I tried updating the highcharts.js reference and the jquery reference to libraries on my hard drive, but that is not working either.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895610/highcharts-cannot-get-example-to-display-chart), which says that the limitation is that Chrome won't let you use ajax to get local files. But I tried it using Firefox and it still did not work.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: I tried this on my home computer and it worked in Firefox, but it continues to fail on my work computer. I am using Firefox 6.0 on the home computer and Firefox 22.0 on the work computer. Did Firefox disable local ajax gets?**

**EDIT 2: Firefox auto-updated to version 12.0 and it still worked. I decided to roll the dice and updated to 22.0 on the home computer. It stopped working. It appears as though Firefox did disable access to local files somewhere between version 12.0 and 22.0**

Comment: What javascript errors are you getting?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know where it is failing, which I think is at the root of my inability to solve to this. Is there a debugger that I should be using? Here is what I know: when I open the "test.htm" file, it is blank (all white). There are no errors displayed.

Comment: You can use firebug in FF

Comment: **Or** In Chrome right-click on page, select "Inspect element", goto console **Or** in IE click F12, goto console.

Comment: Via the Chrome "inspect element" console method, the error is:

Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. file:///C:/Users/rknight/Dropbox/Highcharts/tests/data.csv
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/rknight/Dropbox/Highcharts/tests/data.csv. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. try1.htm:1

So that does indeed seem to be a problem of Chrome not allowing local AJAX gets. However, via Firefox, there are no errors in the console of Firebug. When I use the built in FF editor, it gives me the unhelpful message, "syntax error".

Comment: See my edits. It looks like Firefox behaves like Chrome now. How should I learn java/highcharts without access to local files?

Comment: Instead of using AJAX you can put data in simple string (as it is CSV) and preprocess data as always. Second option is to install XAMPP or WAMP local servers on Windows.